# Console logs are not showing up with rollup plugin in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-chrome-extension, rollupjs

While working on a Chrome extension with manifest version 3, I am having trouble getting the console logs when I am trying to log on service worker JS file.

My code structure looks something like this:

Hello_world_extension

- src

  - app.js
  - sw.mjs
  - manifest.json
  - welcome.html
  - images
- package.json
- rollup.config.mjs

Content of these files look something like this:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Hello World Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "welcome.html",
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "images/16x16.png",
          "32": "images/32x32.png",
          "48": "images/48x48.png",
          "128": "images/128x128.png"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "sw.mjs",
      "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["app.js"]      
      }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 3
}
```

**rollup.config.mjs**

```js
// rollup.config.js

import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

import { chromeExtension, simpleReloader } from 'rollup-plugin-chrome-extension'

export default {
  input: 'src/manifest.json',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'esm',
  },
  plugins: [
    // always put chromeExtension() before other plugins
    chromeExtension(),
    simpleReloader(),
    // the plugins below are optional
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
  ],
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.1",
    "firebase": "^10.5.0",
    "rollup": "^3.29.4",
    "rollup-plugin-chrome-extension": "^3.6.12",
    "rollup-plugin-zip": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.4",
    "corepack": "^0.20.0"
  },
  "name": "Hello World",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development rollup -c -w",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "release": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup -c"
  }
}
```

**sw.mjs**

```js
console.log("hello from sw");
```

**app.js**

```js
console.log("hello from app");
```

I am bundling and running application using command:

```
yarn dev
```

If I go back to extension page and click on service worker on extension page and click on console then I am getting this message instead of my message from the console log.
[image]

Is there a way to the console log message from the service worker when working with rollup and Chrome extension?

Comment: Disable auto-reloader, it doesn't work with service workers. Also use [the background console](/a/10258029).